# JS/JQuery loop chekboxes and call function by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

*I have many inputs with class **filter**:*

```
<ul>
<li>
<a><input class="filter" name="filter[manufacturer][]" type="checkbox"> Other (18)</a>
</li>
<li>
<a><input class="filter" name="filter[manufacturer][JOBY]" type="checkbox"> JOBY (2)</a>
</li>
<li>
<a><input class="filter" name="filter[manufacturer][Beurer]" type="checkbox"> Beurer (1)</a>
</li>
<li><a>
<input class="filter" name="filter[manufacturer][Obreey Products]" type="checkbox"> Obreey Products (1)</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And i need to **loop** every **input** with *JavaScript* or *JQuery* and **call** *cl.facetFilter(name, name2)* **function** if input **checkbox** is **checked**:

For example if checkbox name is **filter[manufacturer][JOBY]** and input is **checked**, i need to **call**:

```
cl.facetFilter('manufacturer', 'JOBY');
```

If checkbox name **filter[manufacturer][]** and input is **checked**, i need to **call**:

```
cl.facetFilter('manufacturer', '');
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest I'd suggest, albeit untested:

```
$('.filter').each(function () {
    var self = this;
    if (self.checked && self.name) {
        var names = self.name.match(/\[(.+)\]/)[1].split('][');
        c1.facetFilter(names[0],names[1]);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PKj8u/).

Note, in the demo I'm, obviously, using a different function-name and also setting the checkboxes to be checked (for the purposes of demonstration).

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(".filter:checked").each(function() {
    var name = $(".filter").attr("name");
    name = name.split("[");

    name[1] = name[1].substring(0, name[1].length - 1);
    name[2] = name[2].substring(0, name[2].length - 1);

    cl.facetFilter(name[1], name[2]);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/MfAsA/ -- I logged the results rather than call a func in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery should do what you need:

```
$('.filter:checked').each(function(index, elem) {
    elem = $(elem);
    var result = elem.attr('name').match(/\[[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\]/g);
    if (result.length == 2) { // Sanity check
        cl.facetFilter(result[0], result[1]);
    }
});
```

The `:checked` portion of the selector should filter out any unchecked input boxes, and the regex match should pick out the values in the two sets of brackets. If that notation isn't necessary, though, I would advise a simpler formatting (e.g. `filter|manufacturer|JOBY`) so you could do a simple .split() on the separator character.

Answer (score 0):

Some icky string manipulation, but this will call the function with the correct parameters when you check the relevant box:

```
$('.filter').click(function(e){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $name = $(this).attr('name');
        $names = $name.split('[');
        $attr1 = $names[1].replace(']', '');
        $attr2 = $names[2].replace(']', '');
        console.log('cl.facetFilter(\''+$attr1+'\', \'' +$attr2+'\')');
    }
});
```

If you're loading the document with some boxes already checked, then the `$('.filter:checked').each(function() {...` syntax will get you there.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8pk9k/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input.filter:checked").each(function() {
    var parts = /\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]/g.exec(this.name);
    cl.facetFilter(parts[1], parts[2]);
});
```